# Go - What is the equivalent of Python's "pass"?

Tags: python, select, go

I have a default cause in a select statement that I want to do nothing, just continue, but leaving the line blank stops anything in the statement from happening

```
        select {
        case quit_status := <-quit:
            if quit_status == true {
                fmt.Printf("********************* GOROUTINE [%d] Received QUIT MSG\n", id)
                return
            }
        default:
            fmt.Printf("GOROUTINE [%d] step: %d, NO QUIT MSG\n", id, i)
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the default statement altogether?

Comment: Can't you just completely omit the `default` clause?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `default` case in a `select` statement is intended to provide non-blocking I/O for channel reads and writes. The code in the `default` case is executed whenever none of the channels in any of the cases are ready to be read/written to.

So in your case, the `default` block is executed if the quit channel has nothing to say.
You can simply remove the default case and it will block on the `quit_status := <-quit` case until a value is available in `quit`.. which is probably what you are after in this instance.

If you want to immediately continue executing code after the select statement, you should run this select statement in a separate goroutine:

```
go func() {
    select {
    case quit_status := <-quit:
        ...

    }
}()

// Execution continues here immediately.
```

Comment: No reason to run it in a another goroutine. You can just put `default:` then on the next line close the select statement. The go version of "pass" is to just put nothing.

Answer (score 3):

As @StephenWeinberg pointed out, there is no pass statement in go. Simply put nothing in the case when the channel hits something.

```golang
select {
    case <-ch:
        // do something
    case <-time.After(2*time.Second):
        // timeout
    default:
        // do nothing aka pass
}
```